# How does Spring AMQP Listener Container Works?

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, amqp, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

How the Listener Container transfers the message to the Listener and what is the internal architecture of Listener Container.How Multi-threading is used in Listener Container .

Comment: You should just go to the project source code and study from there: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/blob/master/spring-rabbit/src/main/java/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/listener/SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java

Comment: How Listener Container receives messages from the Broker ?

Comment: Well, you know you really ask the fundamental questions. Please, consider to read docs: http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/1.7.3.RELEASE/reference/html/